# Trying to use auto.arima and getting message it is not available for this version

Tags: r, forecasting

I have R Version 3.3.1 installed using RStudio. I also installed the forecast package.

When I try to use auto arima, I get a response that it is not available for this version.

Would switching to another version solve this issue? Which R version has auto arima? Or is there another solution entirely?

Comment: What error message are you getting specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The `forecast` package has been available in every R version for about 14 years. It is available in v3.3.1. Most likely you don't have a dependency installed.

Comment: R version -3.3.1 is installed. Forecast package is also installed but AUTO. ARIMA is not working. The message I get get says:

Comment: it tells me that auto.arima is not available for R version 3.3.3.1.